# Webpack transport polling errors

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, gruntjs, webpack

I have the below grunt task in my express/webpack app that starts a webpack-dev-server:

```
"webpack-dev-server": {
    options: {
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        publicPath: '/assets/',
        watch: true,
        inline: true,
        hot: true,
        quiet: true
    },
    start: {
        keepAlive: true,
        webpack: {
            devtool: 'eval',
            debug: true
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the poller just spams my chrome console which is gonna be pretty annoying when it comes to debugging. (I'm in the bare-bones app stage).

[image]

Anybody any ideas at all what could be causing this?

Comment: You have socket.io client side that is asking for server side callback and can't find it. (undefined hostname)

Comment: socket.io is nowhere in my project

Comment: Looks like it is, there's `socket.io` part in it. Maybe you have not included it explicitly but it may be dependency of other dependency which is included by you.

Answer (score 1):

found it myself:

set `host` option in grunt to 'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

Here a [piece of code](https://github.com/webpack/grunt-webpack/blob/master/tasks/webpack-dev-server.js) that produce an error at `grunt-webpack`. By default options set to

```
var options = _.merge({
    port: 8080,
    host: undefined
}, options);
```

And later

```
if (options.inline) {
    var devClient = ["webpack-dev-server/client?" + protocol + "://" + options.host + ":" + options.port];

    ...
}
```

So, to fix your problem specify host options in grunt config

```
"webpack-dev-server": {
    options: {
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        publicPath: '/assets/',
        watch: true,
        inline: true,
        hot: true,
        quiet: true,
        host: 'localhost'
    },
    start: {
        keepAlive: true,
        webpack: {
            devtool: 'eval',
            debug: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I simply didn't see that I got a compile error while trying to run the devserver. This caused the same problem.

I felt pretty dumb after noticing that.